# Why does my python code not draw stars properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, turtle-graphics

So, I run this code and everything works out fine expect the stars are not fully colored. Can you guys tell me why that is? Thanks you

```
import turtle as tu
import random as rn

def draw_star (x,y,color, side):
    tu.color(color)
    tu.begin_fill()
    tu.penup()
    tu.goto(x, y)
    tu.pendown()
    for k in range(5):
        tu.forward (side)
        tu.right(144)
        tu.forward (side)
    tu.end_fill()

def random_length():
    return rn.randrange(40, 70)
def random_xy_coord():
    return rn.randrange(-300,300), rn.randrange(-300, 300)

tu.title('Star')
tu.bgcolor('black')

tu.speed('fast')
colors = ['red','orange','magenta','green','blue','yellow','white']

stars = 10
for k in range(stars):
    color= rn.choice(colors)
    side = random_length()
    x, y = random_xy_coord()
    draw_star(x,y,color,side)

tu.done()
```

Comment: This seems to run fine for me; can you provide more details as to what the problem is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turtle graphic begin\_fill() function does not work correctly on MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55044046/turtle-graphic-begin-fill-function-does-not-work-correctly-on-mac)

Comment: Please post a picture of the result.